# How to initialize state variable with core data model

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I don't know how to initialize a **CoreData** model in my `ContentView`:

This is the declaration line so far:

```
@State var selectedFriend: Friend
```

I want to use the type `Friend` in a **picker** but I don't know how to setup a custom picker so it works with a core data model.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the context. `@State` is actually for value types and needs to be initialized.

Comment: what context do you mean?

Comment: or how to initialize a single entity of a Core Data Model type?

Comment: Is it the main view? Is it a child view? How do you *fetch* the data?

Comment: I have this: `FetchedResults<Friend>`

Comment: it is the main view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fetch the data with `@FetchRequest` and you want to display the data in a picker (no empty selection) my suggestion is to work with indices. A scalar value type can be initialised directly.

```
@State private var selectedFriendIndex = 0


...

Picker("Friend", selection: $selectedFriendIndex) {
    ForEach(0..<friends.count, id: \.self) { index in
        Text(friends[index].name)
    }
}
```